# how to static cast raw array into struct that only consists of reference to array

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, overhead-minimization

I have a performance-critical piece of code where an operator shall return a wrapped reference to a raw array:

```
struct A{
   float (&p)[32]; // << this is the only attribute of A; you may change the type of p into float* but iff there is no other possible solution.
   // ... here follow member-functions of A
};
struct B{
   float (*p)[32]; // << this is mandatory
   A& operator[](size_t i){ return static_cast<A>(p[i]); } // << critical line
};
```

There is no option to replace B with an array of A, because B references data from raw external code.
I could circumvent the issue by changing the member functions of A to non-member functions on float[32], but then I'd have to refactor a significant portion of existing code.

Of course, the cast in the critical line cannot be made. But, I want to accept neither the redundancy of creating an array of A, nor the overhead of constructing (and eventually destructing) an instance of A for every call of operator[].

So how can it be done. Please provide functioning code that achieves the purpose with minimum (ideally none at all) overhead.

Comment: Perhaps use a [`std::ranges::view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges)...?

Comment: This is doable in c++20 but note that all instances of A must be initialized, a c++ requirement, even though they can be changed afterwards. One can initlialze to a dummy array. Then the wrapper can be reseated. Is that OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` only has a single member of reference type. This is extremely easy to construct/destruct. It should have the exact same overhead as returning a pointer.

Just construct a new `A` object with every invocation:

```cpp
struct B{
   float (*p)[32]; // << this is mandatory
   A operator[](unsigned i){ return A{p[i]}; } // << critical line
};
```

And there will be no overhead versus using non-member functions on `float[32]`: https://godbolt.org/z/Md6TP7PPP

Comment: very very interesting! Thank you a lot! I have many questions on the context of when expression templates in a broader context may or not cause overhead and what to do about if whenever that is the case. Please get in touch if you like to offer counselling.

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper for A can be retargeted in c++20 but creating an initial A object also always requires initialization. This can be done to a dummy array.

```
#include <memory>

struct B {
    float(*p)[32]; // << this is mandatory
};

struct A {
    inline static float dummy[32]{};
    float(&p)[32]=dummy; // << this is the only attribute of A; you may change the type of p into float* but iff there is no other possible solution.
    // ... here follow member-functions of A
    A() : p(p) {}  // ctor from B
    A(const B& b, size_t index) : p(b.p[index]) {}  // ctor from B
    A(float(&p)[32]) : p(p) {}  // ctor from array ref
    void reset_an_A_from_B(const B& b, size_t index) {
        std::destroy_at(this);  // this is not needed in this example since A is trivially destructable
        std::construct_at(this, A{ b.p[index] });
    };
};


int main()
{
    float external_arrays[2][32]{};
    B b1{external_arrays};     // contains two arrays of 32 floats

    A a(b1,0);  // construct a from b, first (and only) array
    a.reset_an_A_from_B(b1, 1);    // reset a to refer to second array in b

    // alternately, construct an A initialized by the dummy static array
    A a1;
    a1.reset_an_A_from_B(b1, 0);    // then reset a to refer to first array in a B object

    // To use the reference in A
    float x = a1.p[31];
}
```

This allows one to change what an A object refers to dynamically in the code as needed.